# Dell MUMC: How to shut down servers if any one of two UPSes loses power?

Tags: dell, ups, dell-powervault

We have here two Dell R720 running ESXi (managed with vCenter). Each is connected to the same PowerVault MD3660i storage array.

However the two servers are powered by different UPSes. One UPS (UPS1) for Server1 + MD array, one UPS (UPS2) for the other server.

I have already set up Dell MUMC for shutting down each server (agentless, via vCenter, including VM shutdown) when its UPS runs on battery.

However since both servers are using the same storage array, Server2 hast to shut down in either case: if UPS1 switches off, the array will power off; if UPS2 switches off, the server2 will power off.

MUMC seems to allow for shutting down servers only if both UPSes are on battery (composite device) - but I could not find how to do it if *either* UPS is on battery.

In fact this is exactly "Use case #2" from the manual

ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_rack_infrastructure/dell-line-interactive-tower-ups-1000t_User%27s%20Guide19_en-us.pdf

page 96.

The settings as indicated in the manual do not seem to work.

My question is:

- Which timers to configure on the UPSes
- Which timers to configure for the hosts
- How to set the redundancy level for the composite device (0 or 1)?
- Any other parameters I might have missed?

Comment: Why do you not have the MD storage array plugged into both UPS units?

Comment: The servers are in different racks with about 15m fibre connections between them. Actually there is a storage in each rack (one is a redundant mirror) - but this is not relevant for the shutdown scenario here.